# How to change the colour of the custom radio button when submit in angular 2

Tags: angular, radio-button

I have written a custom control which works perfectly fine, but then i want to change the color of the radio button on submit,

Since i have applied "Required" to it, it is giving me "ng-untouch,invalid" how can i change the color pf radio button on conditional basis

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: What you tried so far ?